# NextJS: Reverting the placeholder text in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, next.js

I have this simple form where I would like to change the placeholder text back.

```
  <form>
    <div className='flex'>
      <input
        className='pl-1 appearance-none block bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500 w-3/4 md:w-1/2 py-3'
        value={input}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-3 px-12 rounded md:ml-3 mt-3 md:mt-0'
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

In the handle submit, I have it like this:

```
    const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState(
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VooQbNHP44M')

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(input)
    setPlaceholder('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VooQbNHP44M')
  }
```

Somehow, after submission, the placeholder text is not reverted back.  Do I miss anything?

Comment: "the placeholder text is not reverted back" Are you every changing the placeholder text? Or are you talking about clearing the text field from actual content? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder

Comment: Probably clearing and set it back to the original text which is 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VooQbNHP44M'

Comment: Then you should be changing `input`. Please carefully read the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to change placeholder at all?

I guess you just want to clear input value after submit?

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Just clear input value and placeholder will be visible again (you might also need to blur currently focused input)
    setInput('')
}
```

And then you don't need dynamic placeholder at all:

```
  <form>
    <div className='flex'>
      <input
        className='pl-1 appearance-none block bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500 w-3/4 md:w-1/2 py-3'
        value={input}
        placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VooQbNHP44M"
        onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-3 px-12 rounded md:ml-3 mt-3 md:mt-0'
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Oh, yes, this works.  I thought I need a dynamic placeholder.